# Can Blender smartly split Objects?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a model of a motorcycle in Blender. This model is split into a few seperate textures/materials such as livery and mechanics. The problem is, that I want to split these materials as for example the exhaust is in the same texture/material as the forks but in real life the exhaust is rough metal while the forks are shiny, but I can only choose one appearance for all of these parts right now. Can Blender split the material into different by itself?

Comment: do you know that you can do face selection and select a material and then just click on "assign" to change the material just for that selected faces?